# Print the results of MD5 function

Tags: c++, md5

I want to print MD5 for some string. For this I have done the the function

```
std::string generateHashMD5(std::string text)
{
    unsigned char * resultHash;
    resultHash = MD5((const unsigned char*)text.c_str(), text.size(), NULL);
    std::string result;
    result += (char *) resultHash;
    return result;
}
```

Mow I want to print the result of this function. I try to version of such function.

```
void printHash(std::string hash)
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) 
    {
         int val = (short) hash[i];
         std::cout<<std::hex<<val<<':';
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}



std::string printHash(std::string hash)
{
     char arrayResult[200];
     for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
          sprintf(&arrayResult[i*2], "%02x", (unsigned short int)hash[i]);
    std::string result;
    result += arrayResult;
    return result;
}
```

The problem is that unfortunately none of it does not show correct result. What should be changed in this function or where is the mistakes?

Comment: Any time you find yourself casting in C++, you're likely making grave mistakes. This is no different. What is `MD5()`? Where is it documented? What does it return?

Comment: Care to show us the output?

Comment: The result of `MD5` is probably already a hex string, you don't need to convert it to hex. Just print it as is.

Comment: It's probably a 128-bit hash value. But no indication of who owns the memory returned. And OP needs to clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

You improperly use `std::string` as a buffer:

```
result += (char *) resultHash;
```

treats resultHash as a c-string, so if there is \0 byte in middle it would not get enough data. If there is no \0 byte you would copy too much and get UB. You should use constructor with size:

```
std::string result( static_cast<const char *>( resultHash ), blocksize );
```

where block size probably is 16. But I would recommend to use `std::array<uint8_t,blocksize>` or `std::vector<uint8_t>` instead os `std::string`, as `std::string` for buffer is very confusing.

Comment: Actually, widening a `char` to `unsigned short` doesn't raise any endianness issues.  But it is unnecessary when `unsigned char` will do.  But you should use the proper length modifier: `sprintf(buff, "%02hhx", (unsigned char)hash[i]);`

Comment: @TobySpeight agree, did not look deeply and just thaught he casted to pointer to short and then dereferenced. My mistake

Answer (score 0):

in case if MD5 returns byte array

`result += (char *) resultHash;
    return result;`

conversion to string will lose numbers after 0 because string constructor interprets input as null-terminated string
so vector can be used or string construction with explicit number of characters.

Still, there are not enough information to say exactly